# Android notifications won't stack

Tags: android, notifications

I'm working on an application that receives messages from a server. When a message is received, a notification appears. When a second message is received, it should stack instead of creating a whole new notification.

I created an interface that has a method that will be run when the message is received.

The `Server` object is where the message is received, and the constructor accepts the interface I mentioned above.

When I initialize the server object, I pass a new instance of the listener interface, in which the method overridden creates the notification. The thought process is that every time a new notification is created, I increase the `NEW_POST_NOTI` integer by one and add it to a group.

My code looks like this:

```
final int PUSHES_GROUP = 67;
int NEW_POST_NOTI = 56;
```

...

```
Server server = new Server((msg) -> {
    nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(ctx);
    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_noti)
        .setContentTitle("New Message")
        .setContentText(msg)
        .setGroup(PUSHES_GROUP) 
        .build();
    nm.notify(NEW_PUSH_NOTI++, noti);
});
```

That same code is run every time a message is received, but creates separate notifications for each message instead of grouping them. I also tried using `setStyle` to make it `InboxStyle`, but I'm not sure how to dynamically add notifications to that. Is there an issue with my logic or am I simply using the Notification APIs incorrectly?

Comment: grouping is for android wear. For android handheld, use inbox style with lines and summary: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html#AddSummary

Comment: You were right. Not as easy as I imagined but fairly simple nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to create an `InboxStyle` instance variable, and call `addLine` on it every time a new message is received. Then, once the app calls `onResume`, reset the `InboxStyle`.

So for example:

```
public class ServerService extends Service {
    ...
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle style = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    private static NotificationManagerCompat nm;
    private final Context ctx = Server.this;
    Server server;
    private static int pendingPushes = 0;
    private final int NEW_PUSH_NOT = 2;
    ...
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent i, int f, final int s) {
        nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(ctx);
        try {
            server = new Server((msg) -> {
                pendingPushes++; 
                style.setBigContentTitle(pendingPushes +" new pushes");                      
                style.addLine(msg);
                Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_noti)
                        .setStyle(style)
                        .setGroupSummary("Click here to view")
                        .setNumber(pendingPushes) //Should make the number in bottom right the amount of pending messages but not tested yet
                        .build();
                nm.notify(NEW_PUSH_NOT, noti);
             });
             server.start();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Then I created a method to restart the pending count, and close the notification. I run that in my `MainActivity` inside of the `onResume()`

```
public static void resetPendingPushes() {
    pendingPushes = 0;
    style = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    if (nm != null) {
        nm.cancel(NEW_PUSH_NOT);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ServerService.resetPendingPushes();
}
```

Thanks to everyone who answered, you helped a bunch!!
To anyone with a similar question, sorry if there's typos in my answer, I typed it up from my cell rather quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to make use of `Notification ID` which is used in `NotificationManager`. This NotificationID basically represents a unique ID per application so if you use the same notification id then you will be able to club all your notifications. Try the following and let me know.

```
static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
```

Declare a static Notification ID like that. And notify with the same!
So instead of

```
nm.notify(NEW_PUSH_NOTI++, noti);
```

You write

```
nm.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
```

Comment: It wasn't just this. Check my answer.